# Python: How to scrape data inside an iframe when you need to scroll down

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[image]

I used webdriver to login to a website, and I found that the data I wanted to extract is inside an iframe. Like a picture above. At first, I used xpath helper to get me the whole data table.

```
select_box2 =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='k-selectable']/tbody").text
print(select_box2)
```

But I can only extract 7 datas (Total are 400).
Everytime when I scrolled down manually, I can see another part of data, but cannot do the whole at the same time. Any suggestion?

Comment: Relevant _HTML_ please.

Comment: @DebanjanB which part? since the whole one is too big :)

Comment: Are you sure all of the data is in a single `<tbody>` element? Selenium shouldn't need to scroll the viewport to query DOM elements.

Comment: @Ian Nope, I can only see the first 7 datas, if I scroll down, I can see another 7.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm asking what *Selenium* can see. When you use Selenium to find elements in the DOM, it captures whatever exists, regardless of whether it is visible to *you* at that moment. To be certain about what is actually present in the DOM, you'll need to use your browser's developer tools to inspect the live DOM tree. E.g., in Chrome, you can right-click on the table and select "Inspect" to see the full tree. From there, you should be able to see how many elements are actually in the `<tbody>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Recently i did a script to scrape data from instagram

there i need to sroll down the page to load more items

The strategy was:

- get a refence of a element at the botton of the page;
- scroll the page until the element be visible;

something like

```
driver.get(url)

items = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("li") #get a list of items

q = len(items)
li_text = items[q-1].text.splitlines() #in this case i looking for the penultimate element
li = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(.,'"+li_text[1]+"')]") #get the element reference with find_element()

li.location_once_scrolled_into_view #scroll down
```

[source](https://github.com/guilhermebferreira/selenium-notebooks/blob/master/Login%20on%20instagram.ipynb)

Comment: oh thanks! I will try this asap and let you know the result :D The thing is, I have to scroll down in iframe, but not with windows one, not sure if this is the same issue?

Comment: in my case, was something like that, if you could locate the html element, you can scroll to make it visible

Comment: I am trying to learn from your code by scraping public instagram. but cannot find "li" tag name. Would you please tell me where is it? I still need to try for a few days, but will give you a upvote after that. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Makiyo take a look here https://github.com/guilhermebferreira/selenium-notebooks/blob/master/Login%20on%20instagram.ipynb